# InfoPath migration to SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate, sharepoint-designer

Good day beautiful people,

**Overall description**

I have been assigned to a project where recruiters are using excel file to gather information about new joiners, leavers and people changing positions. Later on it is uploaded to SharePoint where this data is connected to some other files, dashboards and so on. There is also a copy of it, in InfoPath, but the program is working terribly wrong so personally for me this is no-go zone.

**My goal**

I would like to make this more automated and user friendly, so that's why I wanted to move it to the SharePoint. I want users to have one page, subpage, app to fill up necessary data, edit it if needed and then publish to the SharePoint.

**Problem**

I have visited tens of pages how to create SharePoint form without InfoPath, how to create SP form with PowerApps but most of these articles provides nothing useful. Just brief overview and I am not that power user of SP to get this done in no time.

**Question**

Is there a way, that I can make this working within accepted mater of time (few days) so the end result will be exactly what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Make some lists in SharePoint with the columns they need, use that as your data source. Link your PowerApps application to that source, et voila. Recruitment can now fill their data in with what you need, and via Power Automate you can process the data and send it to the correct locations afterwards.